# An incomplete metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]

[image]

I didn't understand the last part, would someone be kind enough to explain it to me? More precisely, because since $x$ is continuous we can conclude that

$$x(t)=0\quad\text{if}\; t\in \left[0,\frac{1}{2},\right)\quad x(t)=1\quad\text{if}\; t\in \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$$

Answer (score 2):

The first summand on the right-hand side is an integral of the non-negative continous function $|x(t)|$. Since the left-hand side converges to $0$ this integral must equal zero. Hence $|x(t)|=0$, because otherwise continuity would imply the existence of an intervall $[a,b]\subseteq [0,\frac{1}{2})$ on which the function is positive. But then

$
\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}}|x(t)|\, dt\geq\int\limits_a^{b}|x(t)|\,dt>0.
$

The third summand of the right-hand side can be treated in much the same way replacing $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ by the increasing intervals $(a_m,1]\subset (\frac{1}{2},1]$.